# ListView coming back as null

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to populate a `ListView` with an `ArrayList` from a `Fragment` in Android and it's not working out. I'm getting an error saying that `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`.

Where should I initialize the `ListView` in order for it to be ready for the `onActivityCreated` method?

**Fragment.java**

```
    private static final String TAG = SystemConditionsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private ListView lv;

    private ListAdapter adapter;

    private ArrayList<String> alerts;

    private ProgressDialog progDailog;

    public SystemConditionsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SystemConditionsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SystemConditionsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SystemConditionsFragment fragment = new SystemConditionsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_system_conditions, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    return rootView;
}

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        refresh();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {

        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading","Please wait...", true);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);

        progDailog.dismiss();

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JsonOrgModule());

        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting events data");
        VolleyUtils.makeJsonObjectRequest(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "events",
                new VolleyResponseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String message) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting events: " + message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Received events response " + response);

                        DataRestResponse<SysCondRecord> data = mapper.convertValue(
                                response,
                                new TypeReference<DataRestResponse<SysCondRecord>>() {});
                        // Group by timestamp
                        ImmutableMultimap<DateTime, SysCondRecord> indexedData =
                                Multimaps.index(data.getData(),
                                        new Function<SysCondRecord, DateTime>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public DateTime apply(SysCondRecord record) {
                                                return record.getTimeStamp();
                                            }
                                        });
                        alerts = new ArrayList<>();
                        final List<DateTime> timestamp = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (SysCondRecord record : data.getData()) {
                            timestamp.add(record.getTimeStamp());
                            alerts.add(record.getMessage());
                        }

                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_system_conditions, R.id.listView, alerts);


                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
    }
```

**fragment_system_conditions.xml**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sysCondView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />
```

**Edit**

I was in fact using wrong ID guys, my bad! But I seem to have made things worse...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xx.xxx.com, PID: 26183


java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Comment: Does `fragment_system_conditions.xml` contain a ListView with `android:id="@+id/sysCondView"`? That's one reason you'll get null

Comment: Okay, so you are trying to find `R.id.sysCondView`.... but your ListView has an id of `R.id.listView`... what is `sysCondView`?

Comment: Nice spot @cricket_007. I haven't seen the edited version with the xml. Great work man, I've been following you here on SO for 4 months or so, when you had like 3k rep. Big fan :D

Comment: Different error, but at least you have the listview now. The problem is the adapter. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `findViewById`, you need to look at the XML for the `android:id` attribute.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"               <!-- This line -->
    android:layout_below="@+id/sysCondView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />
```

Also, the `@+id` syntax is only to be used for **adding** id's to the resources, when you want to refer to  them, only use `"@id/sysCondView"` (without the `+`).

You should also have an actual view with that id before the reference in the `RelativeLayout`.

---

Second Problem

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Is referring to this line

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_system_conditions, R.id.listView, alerts);
```

Both of those `R.layout` and `R.id` parameters are incorrect.

You can either define [your own custom adapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter), or use

```
ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

Where the `resource` corresponds to a TextView like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, in which case every object in the `objects` list will be `toString()`'d.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated. I just started with Android last week

Comment: Welcome. There definitely is a learning curve for the basics. Took me a few months to get used to it, but the examples in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) are very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to initialize the View items in onResume(), so when the screen orientation is changed they are reconnected. But then, I also try to avoid Fragments if I can, make stuff more complex, certainly if you have only one.

Comment: I'm new to Android. I've got multiple Fragments

Comment: I think last point you can set it is here: onStart() What are the points you have tried to put it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply move this initialization:

```
lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Into your `onCreateView` like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_system_conditions, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    return rootView;
}
```

**EDIT**: You were using the wrong `id` for the listview, replace that with `R.id.listView`.

Comment: I still get a null pointer but on the Adapter this time  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`

Comment: That just means we're 1 step closer to the solution , don't you agree? Let me take a look again...

Comment: Avoid using `getView().findViewById` and do `rootview.findViewById` like in my answer. also try and put this `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_system_conditions, R.id.listView, alerts);   lv.setAdapter(adapter);` in `onCreateView` as well.

Comment: Adding `lv.setAdapter(adapter)` to onCreateView moved the error but it is still present at that line

Comment: haha well dude you're using the wrong id, spotted well by @cricket_007. Replace `R.id.sysCondView` with proper id of the listview!

Comment: Thanks, work's starting to pickup, so I'm not on as frequently. :D

Comment: Yeah, me too, college and work. But you're crazy man, like 10k points in less than 4 months :D I wish I could've progressed as quickly. I got 1.7k in that time span :)